# Can't search table by string in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table of fake professors and some relevant info. I can search by id, latitude, and longitude, but any LIKE searches on the string columns (i.e. name, university, school) come up empty. I'm doing the searches directly through phpMyAdmin so I doubt it's a MySQL syntax error.

The MySQL query I'd use would be:

```
SELECT * FROM `profs` WHERE `name` LIKE '%doug%';
```

Whether through phpMyAdmin or direct code, any combination of Doug, doug, oug, and even single letters brings back an empty search.

Here's a couple screenshots of the rows and some column info.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show an example of one of your like queries

Comment: @DZDomi phpMyAdmin has a built in search function that doesn't return MySQL code, but if I were to do it myself, it wouldn't probably look like: SELECT * FROM `profs` WHERE `name` LIKE '%doug';

Comment: Maybe `WHERE name LIKE CONVERT('%doug%' USING utf8)`?

Comment: From the dropdown, are you picking "Like" or "Like %...%"?